# Silverlight: Centering After ScaleTransform

Tags: silverlight

I learned how to get a ScrollViewer's scrollbars to display after scaling an element within in a ScrollViewer from this post: http://www.eightyeightpercentnerd.dreamhosters.com/?p=92

Now, I'm trying to get the scaled object (a canvas in this case) to center correctly within the ScrollViewer.  I'm going to let images tell my story here (please help me before Screencast.com purges my files). ;

My XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    Width="300" Height="300" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="White">

    <Canvas x:Name="DesignSurface" Background="Red">

        <Canvas x:Name="Surface" Background="Blue" Height="100" Width="100">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="SurfaceScaleTransform" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <!-- ... -->
        </Canvas>

    </Canvas>

</ScrollViewer>
```

On initial load, my blue canvas is centered and at 100%:
[image]

After decreasing by 50%, the blue canvas is still centered:
[image]

After increasing 400% and scrolling to display the top left corner of the blue canvas:
[image]

After increasing 400% and scrolling to display the bottom right corner of the blue canvas:
[image]

So my question is simply how do I get the blue canvas centered correctly in the ScrollViewer or red canvas or whatever?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I got you wrong, but have you tried setting RenderTransformOrigin to the Canvas? E.g.:

```
    <Canvas x:Name="Surface" Background="Blue" Height="100" Width="100" 
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="SurfaceScaleTransform" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <!-- ... -->
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: That's just what I was going to suggest.

Comment: I tried using both RenderTransformOrigin and setting the CenterX and CenterY values for the ScaleTransform and it worked fine scaling down but not up.  I just solved my problem though by setting the top and left values of the "blue" canvas based on some logic (depending on if the scaled "blue" canvas is smaller than or greater than the ScrollViewer.  It works fine now.  Thanks for the help.